# MongooseJS - How to save document and referenced document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Request.findOne({_id: id}).populate("user").exec(function(err, request) {
    if (!err) {
        request.user.firstname = firstname;
        request.date = date;
        request.save(next);
    }
```

After save, date has changed but the user's firstname has not.
Model :

```
  var Request = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
```

I can still do it by doing

```
     request.user.save(function(err){
        if(!err)
            request.save(next)
     });
```

But why doesn't the first one work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the 'Updating Refs' section of the Mongoose [documentation on populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

You will see there, in the example, that you still must save both the `Request` and `User` documents you have created.  (*In the example, they first save the user 'guille' then in the callback they save the 'story'.*)

In Mongoose, [SubDocs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) save when a parent doc saves but `.populate` does not do this.

Answer (score 5):

`request` and `user` are documents in separate collections so they each require their own `save` operation.  That's simply the way Mongoose works (and MongoDB in general) as no update operation affects more than one collection at a time.